# how randomly select the word from 26 letters using C language?

Tags: c

I want codes for randomly selects the word (meaningful or meaningless) from 26 letters. The word contain 6 letters. I have the codes for C program or objective C, or you will give any idea to me.

Comment: Can letters be repeated?  What have you tried so far?  Also, is this homework?

Comment: its not home work, its for my project work in objective c in n iphone sdk.. please help me.. and letters also be repeated.so please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        putchar('a' + (rand() % 26));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Salt to taste.

### Update0

It would seem the OP does not know how to compile the above. If saved into a file called `so.c`, compile it with `make so CFLAGS=-std=c99` from the same folder.

Comment: Note that this requires a contiguous alpha series (`a` thru `z` being a single area of the character set). That's true for 99.9% of environments out there but it's not mandated by the standard (and I work on one machine where it doesn't hold true - damn EBCDIC). I'm also not a big fan of naked `main`s - I'd prefer on of the two canonical versions, in this case probably `int main(void)`. Neither of those warrant a downvote, just thought I'd mention them.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you'll probably get some anal retentive types insisting that `randnum % 26` skews the distribution since the number of possibilities of randnum is not an _exact_ multiple of 26. Ignore them. That may matter for serious statisticians and cryptos but the vast majority of people couldn't care less :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's an example only, the emphasis is intentionally not on the signature of main. Also I agree with your comment about the skew. It really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Written by kaizer.se */
void randword(char *buf, size_t len)
{
  char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    size_t idx = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX) * (sizeof(alphabet) -1);
    buf[i] = alphabet[idx];
  }
  buf[len] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[1024];

  srand(time(NULL));

  randword(buf, 7);
  printf("Word: %s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ ./rword 
Word: xoilfvv
```